# how to make an api if i have a database without data

Tags: java, android, api, android-room

I am very new to the backend and I need your help since I do not understand how a database communicates with the api. I have developed a mobile app with java (I use the android studio IDE) and I was using the ORM room to store the data until I realized that this orm only works locally (bad luck for me). In order for users to be able to remotely access the data, I must use an mvvm architecture consuming apis to fill the db. The issue is that I want to create my own api to which to make http queries but I don't know how to fill in the api, since the fields that I want to add depend on the mobile app, let me explain: the idea is that the api has logging fields (among others) such as : id, username, email, etc, information that must be sent to the api using the http Post method. My question is, is it a bad practice to Post after the user clicks on a button and send that information to the api and then do a get to see all the users, or should I have a database filled with information with users previously in the database and then pass them to the pi and after that read the data before doing the queries (?)

Comment: MVVM is a UI pattern.  It is not required to talk to a remote database or web api.  The actual question part of your post isn't really clear.  You want to use a POST to add data to the database?  That's fairly standard.  And then a GET to fetch the data?  Also standard, although a naive return everything at once API may not scale.